# OCPP Python Package Documentation

Tags: python, async-await, ocpp

I'm searching for documentation for the Python ocpp package. I want to program a backend, to interact with a Bender CC612 Charging Controller. I'm able to get a connection, even without errors, but I don't know how to proceed.

Does anyone already worked with ocpp and ocpp for Python and created an own backend and can maybe give me some resources?

Comment: something like [this](https://www.ampcontrol.io/post/how-to-send-ev-charging-profiles-to-your-open-charge-point-protocol-ocpp-charging-station)?

Comment: kind of, but maybe for the python ocpp package. The ocpp manual from oasis-open.org is quite helpful, too. But it is very difficult for me to adapt it into python.

Comment: Appears like the OCPP python package is badly documented... I'm at a loss too. Near to no examples aside from that short one in the README, no API documentation whatsoever... horrible... guess we're on our own.

Answer (score 3):

I also received Bender CC613 Charging controller and I am trying to educate myself around how it works and how to implement the OCPP backend for it. Here are some resources I found so far:

- [OCPP github repo for Scala](https://github.com/NewMotion/ocpp). Well, it is Scala implementation of OCPP, but it seems to have much better documentation than ocpp python package and I believe it would be a nice starting point. Especially that:

  > This library is the implementation of OCPP developed and used by NewMotion, one of Europe's largest Electric Vehicle Charge Point Operators.
- Youtube video from OCA - [OCPP 2.0.1 Tutorial - Open Charge Alliance Webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-R18CsSKYI). I learned from this video that OCPP 1.6 (which unfortunately is the top supported version of OCPP for Bender CC613 Charging Controllers) documentation is confusing. They have completely rewrite the OCPP with version 2.0. So I think I would try and have a go at documentations for OCPP 2.0 and then eventually come back to OCPP 1.6 documentation with hopefully much more understanding.
- There is apparently a [reddit for OCPP](https://www.reddit.com/r/ocpp/) which has lead me to this post about [OCPP Central System using Python](https://www.reddit.com/r/ocpp/comments/o4ywu9/ocpp_central_system_using_python/). Seems like we are on our own (as Hendrik Wiese mentioned) but.. not alone.
- The forementioned reddit for OCPP has lead me to find a [discord channel for OCCP](https://discord.com/invite/XtqFZcfXzA)
- [SteVe](https://github.com/RWTH-i5-IDSG/steve) - OCPP Server implementation in Java. That is a platform that is known to work well with Bender devices (according to the representative that supplies us the Bender devices).

I will keep on adding resources here as I dig more into the topic. I hope they will be useful in some way or the other.

Comment: I forked the mobilityhouse/occp repo and went through the OCPP 1.6 protocol to create a simple backend without the logic implemented to process the server initiated actions. I also uploaded a minimal version of a chargepoint, so that you can see, how a possible implementation of logic could look like. I will continiously work on the repo this year, because it will be part of my masters thesis so if you got some questions, just write a message. https://github.com/c0nr3f/ocpp/tree/master/examples/v16

Comment: do you have experience with ISO IEC 15118 and how to implement the Power Line Communication as hard- and software ?

Comment: @c0nr3f No, sorry. I'm just starting to educate myself about this topic.